# Shift focus to View(Button) from ViewGroup(ListView item)

Tags: android, listview, android-view, viewgroup, android-viewgroup

I have a ListView with 'N' number of items and each item(ViewGroup) in the List have some views like Image View,Text View and few buttons as shown in below image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0cUDScxLAxfRXRNemphazhPd1k/view?usp=sharing

My requirement is while scrolling in ListView if I press Left/Right key in D-Pad then either left most or right most button should focus and focus on whole list view Item should disappear.

I am tried with **android:nextFocusDown()** in xml and **setNextFocusDownId(int)**

but not working.

Am i need to add other parameters in xml/java??

**Note: I have D-pad in my application/Device.**

Answer (score 0):

### I achieved this by creating 'CustomListView'.

I extended *ListView* in *CustomListView*

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView
{
public CustomListView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}
```

and i override ***onKeyDown*** and ***onKeyUp*** and i am setting values to [setItemsCanFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setItemsCanFocus(boolean)) and [setDescendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setDescendantFocusability(int)).

**Hope my solution will help you.**